# v1.1.0 to v2.1.0 => armeabi ABI dropped

Tags: android, realm

I'm using Realm in my Android project for several months, with Realm 1.1.0. I just went to see if there is any update available and I saw 2.1.0 popped out few weeks ago.
After I synced my project with Gradle files and launched the app, it just crashed with the exception :

> com.getkeepsafe.relinker.MissingLibraryException: lib/armeabi/librealm-jni.so

So I checked realm-android-library-2.1.0.aar and saw that you removed the "/jni/armeabi/" directory.
The problem is that my project includes another library containing JNI libs for armeabi and x86 ABIs only. So for it to work with Realm on every devices (arm64-v8a, armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86 and x86_64), I had to filter the included native libs like this (build.gradle):

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86','armeabi'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

Now that you dropped the armeabi/ directory, I'm a bit in trouble.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: In the meantime, stick to Realm 1.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the use case you describe was one we unfortunately did not consider when removing ARM support. However, it has become clear that a lot of apps are in the same position as you, so we are in the process of re-adding ARM support.

You can follow this issue: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3506